# Identifying HTTP requests

Tags: iis, sharepoint, wsus

So I'm looking to remove IIS from a few servers we used to have WSUS running on but machines are still contacting it (albeit very few) and I can't fathom where some of the requests are coming from.

For instance, a local client is requesting 2 shares and a GPO from the local DC (which had WSUS installed previously). The server responds to the initial OPTIONS command with a HTTP 200, and subsequent WebDAV PROPFIND commands with a 404.

I've included the most recent requests from 8 days ago below. Anyone out there know what would be generating these requests? Note that they occur at 04:58 am. It's a client workstation from the IP it's picked up and has probably been left on overnight.

```
>2011-10-12 04:48:48 10.10.10.20 OPTIONS /templates.user - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 200 0 0 4227
2011-10-12 04:48:48 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /templates.user - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 15
2011-10-12 04:48:50 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /templates.group - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:48:51 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /templates.group - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:48:51 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /templates.group/ - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:55:15 10.10.10.20 OPTIONS /templates.user - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 200 0 0 15
2011-10-12 04:55:15 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /templates.user - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:58:53 10.10.10.20 OPTIONS /SysVol/<company domain>/Policies/{342671BC-3BA8-4A16-3DB7-C2BA9060F772}/User/Scripts/Logoff - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 200 0 0 15
2011-10-12 04:58:53 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /SysVol/<company domain>/Policies/{342671BC-3BA8-4A16-3DB7-C2BA9060F772}/User/Scripts/Logoff - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:58:53 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /SysVol/<company domain>/Policies/{342671BC-3BA8-4A16-3DB7-C2BA9060F772}/User/Scripts - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:58:55 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /SysVol/<company domain>/Policies/{342671BC-3BA8-4A16-3DB7-C2BA9060F772}/User/Scripts/Logoff/LogoffScript.vbs - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
2011-10-12 04:58:55 10.10.10.20 PROPFIND /SysVol/<company domain>/Policies/{342671BC-3BA8-4A16-3DB7-C2BA9060F772}/User/Scripts/Logoff - 80 - 10.10.10.125 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002 404 0 2 0
```

Anyone out there know what might be generating these requests? It doesn't appear to be WSUS related, perhaps Sharepoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you've got a wacky client system trying to use WebDAV instead of SMB to access GPO files in sysvol - coincidence that it appeared on this domain controller, since it has IIS running from that old WSUS install.

In Network Connections, Advanced menu -> Advanced Settings, make sure the "Web Client" provider is below the normal options in the provider order.

[image: webclient]

Or just disable the Web Client service.  But, yeah, feel free to strip IIS from this DC - the WebDAV attempts are failing anyway (for good reason), so it's not like you'll break anything.